# Override display in css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap on Asp.net MVC. I have a custom Styles.css that I am using to set values that I want changed from the default values in the bootstrap.css.

I am trying to get two textbox next to each other for MM YY (month year).

In bootstrap it has:

```
display: block;
```

In my Styles.css I created this to overwrite that value:

```
.disableblock{
  display: inline;
}
```

This is the line in my .cshtml:

Expiration Date

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExpirationDateMonth, new { @class = "form-control expirationdatetextbox disableblock", @maxlength = "2", placeholder = "MM" })
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExpirationDateYear, new { @class = "form-control expirationdatetextbox", @maxlength = "2", placeholder = "YY" })
</div>

<div class="warning">
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ExpirationDateMonth)
</div>
```

When I display it in IE, it shows the following:

[image]

If I uncheck the `display: block;` it puts the two textboxes on the same line.

Why isn't the Styles.css inline not overwriting the block in bootstrap.css?d

**EDIT**

For those questioning the css call order:

```
  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
    "~/Content/site.css",
    "~/Content/justified-nav.css",
    "~/Content/Styles.css")); // <-- Custom CSS file
```

This is from the view source:

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/justified-nav.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: You just need to add disableblock to the ExpirationDateYear input as well.

Comment: @Alohci that was it! Too simple. Make that your answer and I'll upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `!important` after your display value. If that doesn't work, make sure that when you are loading in your bootstrap code you are doing so before your custom css. Sometimes if you load your custom css first bootstrap seems to override even if you're using `!important`. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I tried the important and it did not make any difference. :(

Comment: Could there be something in your codebase that's loading in bootstrap independently of the ordering in the HTML link elements? Perhaps something in the ASP.net code?

Answer (score 0):

You can

- add !important after the override style so: display: inline !important;
- Reorder your styles reference so that styles.css is after bootstrap
- Be more specific with your selector: input.form-control.displayblock {}